# How do I disable a menu on Iphone?

Tags: iphone

Hey sorry if it's not really on topic but it's immediate. Today a menu popped up on my iphone and I can't use the touch screen. How do I disable it ? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGQMM.jpg)

Comment: Try asking on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'd hard reset... Perhaps hold down the power and volume button for 15-30 seconds?